# How to get 12 months of the year

Tags: android

With this statement, I return day of the week

```
int dayOfWeak = mycal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        switch (dayOfWeak) {
            case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                break;
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                break;
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                break;
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                break;
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                break;
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                break;
            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                break;
```

but how can I do to get the 12 months to pass to the display adapter?

Comment: Have you tried to check constants of Calendar class?

Comment: tried to put months of the year, then I do not know how to put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and use pattern `MMMM`

```
public String getMonth(){
  String format = "MMMM";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
  return sdf.format(DATE_WITH_SPECIFIED_MONTH);
}
```

or different pattern when you want to get an Integer value.

```
public int getMonth(){
  String format = "M";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
  return sdf.format(DATE_WITH_SPECIFIED_MONTH);
}
```

Comment: but if I want to get the list of months, one of the places of days as I have to put?

Comment: I would like to get the id of the month

Comment: I did't understand that `get the list of months, one of the places of days` what it mean? You want to get list of month based on what?

Comment: simply the names of the months, however in the meantime I solved, thanks